# What is the App-V 5.0 alternative to sfttray \launch without the \exe parameter in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, appv

I'm trying to transition a set of Powershell scripts that launches App-V applications, after upgrading the App-V server from version `4.x` to `5.x`. Previously, I used the following command to do so:

```
sfttray.exe /launch $appName
```

The [`sfttray` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/appv-v4/sfttray-command-reference) introduced an optional `/exe` switch when running the `/launch` command:

```
Used with /LAUNCH to specify that an executable program is to be started in 
the virtual environment when a virtual application is started in place of 
the target file specified in the OSD.
```

I've read that App-V `5.x` has done away with the `sfttray.exe`, and my alternative is to use the [Start-AppvVirtualProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appvclient/start-appvvirtualprocess?view=win10-ps) cmdlet. It seems that `Start-AppvVirtualProcess` requires two parameters: `AppvClientObject` and `FilePath`. Every example I've seen so far has been of the following format:

```
Start-AppvVirtualProcess -FilePath "C:\Calc.exe" -AppvClientObject $appVObj
```

This launches `Calc.exe` within the passed in App-V Object, and seems to be the App-V `5.x` equivalent of:

```
sfttray.exe /launch $appVObj.Name /exe Calc.exe
```

But what if I don't want to launch an alternate program? How do I get the file path to the target application in the `.appv` package?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of launching a local system process inside of an App-V package. Thes first is the one you described, but you can also launch any process with /appvve: command switch, and windows will open it in the specified application package or connection group.

```
cmd.exe /appvve:<PACKAGEGUID_VERSIONGUID>
cmd.exe /appvve:aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeee_11111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555
```

For more information see this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2848278/how-to-launch-processes-inside-the-app-v-5-0-virtualized-environment).